# byte casting when use NOT operator

Tags: java, types, casting

Why I need to use variable casting in this example?

```
byte b = -123;
b = (byte) ~b;
```

When I am trying to compile it without casting, I get:

```
NotDemo.java:17: error: possible loss of precision
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because with most Java operators (`~` included), integer operands are [*promoted*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion#Type_promotion) before the operator is applied.  So `byte` is promoted to `int`; your code is equivalent to this:

```
b = (byte) ~((int) b);
```

Therefore in general, assigning back to a `byte` will lose information in the upper bits.  (Although it's pretty meaningless in this case.)

Answer (score 4):

Because ~b will convert/promote b to int before applying the ~.

Actually what invisibly happens is something like this.

```
~((int)b);
```

So the result is of type int.

And so you need the cast back to byte.

See the JLS for more details.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.5